# how to paste text into tinymce without some style

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

Hello I have tinymce textarea and when I paste text from microsoft word spacing and line height is incorrect or looks ugly . I want to remove only spacing and line height when user paste text. something like native textarea makes it. I have no any idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `paste` **plugin** and `paste_as_text` Refer [Doc](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/paste/)

Set your other option for menu etc as per your usage.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "yourselector",  // change this value according to your HTML
  plugins: "paste",
  paste_as_text: true
});
```

Comment: I using that but is not works. it removes only style and spacing and line-height is same like Word

Comment: have you check other options of DOC ?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to add `paste_retain_style_properties` to your `tiny.init()` configuration. [Here's the documentation for that setting](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/paste/#paste_retain_style_properties).

This option allows you to specify which specific styles you want to **retain** when pasting contents from Word (and similar products). This option can be set to a space-separated list of CSS style names, or "all" if you want all styles to be retained.

For example:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",  // change this value according to your HTML
  paste_retain_style_properties: "color font-size"
});
```

For more control over pasted content, you could utilize TinyMCE's [PastPostProcess callback](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/paste/#paste_postprocess).

This enables you to parse and filter pasted content before it gets inserted into the editor.

Comment: FYI, from the docs: "This option has been deprecated in TinyMCE 5.10 and will be removed in TinyMCE 6.0"

Comment: That is because they moved the feature into a paid plugin :(